How can I add the information about heterogeneity in the forest() in metafor package?
So here is my code for the forest plot:
forest(res2, showweights = TRUE, 
       shade="zebra2", 
       alim=c(log(0.2), log(5)),            
       atransf=exp,
       at = log(c(0.20, 0.25, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 4.00, 5.00)), digits = 2,# Transform to exp for odds ratios
       psize=0.75,                      
       xlim=c(-3,3), 
       xlab="Odds ratio", 
       refline=log(1),
       cex=0.9, cex.lab = 0.6, cex.axis = 0.7)your text

I would like to add the information about the heterogeneity on it, but I can't seem to put it under the x-axis, which would be the best option here. Any advice?
I tried to just add it below the plot:
text(-3, -1.5, paste0("Heterogeneity: I² = ", I2, "%, τ² = ", tau2, ", p-value = ", Q_pval), pos=4, cex=0.7)
But it puts it right above the x-axis, and if I move it lower it gets covered by the axis.

While using mtext() as noted by @edward is one option, you can stick to using text() but first run par(xpd=NA) before your call to text() (and then par(xpd=FALSE) afterwards). This will allow you to place the text anywhere on the plotting device.
You might also like to take a look at this example of a forest plot on the metafor package website. It shows how to add nicer information about heterogeneity to the plot. You can of course also place the text below the RE Model part.

You could use mtext instead of text here for plotting text in the margins. Here, you can place the text on the line above (line=-1) the bottom x-axis (side=1). You can play around with these two and other arguments to position the text virtually anywhere you like.
library(metafor)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat, slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

forest(res, showweights = TRUE, 
       shade="zebra2", 
       alim=c(log(0.2), log(5)),            
       atransf=exp,
       at = log(c(0.20, 0.25, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 4.00, 5.00)), digits = 2,
       psize=0.75,                      
       xlim=c(-3,3), 
       xlab="Odds ratio", 
       refline=log(1),
       cex=0.9, cex.lab = 0.6, cex.axis = 0.7)

I2 <- 0.2
tau2 <- 0.9
Q_pval <- 0.02

mtext(paste0("Heterogeneity: I² = ", I2, "%, τ² = ", tau2, ", p-value = ", Q_pval), 
      cex=0.7, side=1, line=-1)

Giving:

